# How can I compare two ISO 8061 durations in PHP?

Tags: php, compare, duration, iso

I have two ISO 8061 durations, `PT11M41S` and `PT49M13S`. How can I compare them? (I need a boolean value that indicates if the first duration is major than the second one.)

Comment: Hi, have you tried anything. You will always get a better response from the community if you show us some code, and it helps us by giving us a little context of what you are actually trying to do

Comment: Attention: If you use fuzzy units like months then a reliable comparison might be impossible, for example P1M ~ P30D (result is not clear!!!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the PHP DateTime object quite simply

```
<?php 

$t1 = 'PT11M41S';
$t2 = 'PT49M13S';

$d1 = new DateTime();
$d2 = new DateTime();

$d1->add(new DateInterval($t1));
$d2->add(new DateInterval($t2));

$diff =  $d1 > $d2 ? true : false;
echo $diff ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

Comment: *Easy as pie* ;-)

Comment: :) Does that mean i get `3.14159265359` upvotes @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: "pie" and "pi" are two different animals; you know that ;-) Mmmm... pie.

Answer (score 0):

I see a really good answer here but I just want to add that there are so many ways to achieve this properly.For example :

```
class ExDateInterval extends DateInterval{
    public function toSeconds($daysInMonth=30){
        $daysInMonth=!is_int($daysInMonth)||$daysInMonth>31||$daysInMonth<28?30:$daysInMonth;
        $interval=$this->y*31536000+$this->d*86400+$this->h*3600+$this->i*60+$this->s+$this->m*$daysInMonth*86400;
        return $interval;
    }
}

$t1='PT11M41S';
$t2='PT49M13S';

$interval1=new ExDateInterval($t1);
$interval2=new ExDateInterval($t2);

var_dump($interval1->toSeconds()>$interval2->toSeconds());//output false
var_dump($interval1->toSeconds()===$interval2->toSeconds());//output false
var_dump($interval1->toSeconds()<$interval2->toSeconds());//output true
```